# Swift Changing Navigation ViewController stack (programatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having some trouble with the logic in my application.

I have been looking for a way to change the navigation controller's viewcontroller stack.

For several reasons.

One, I have a login and sign up page, which each have buttons pushing to the other view controller. Creating an /infinite/ loop being able to go between them.

I also need to change the topViewController, to my dashboard_VC after the user has logged in. So the back button to the login page doesn't show up...

I've been trying to find a solution for a while. I've mainly been looking at rootViewController, until I realized that's probably not the one I'm looking for since my rootViewController is my navigationController and not my first View Controller in the stack.

So I tried to change the stack with this:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([LandingPageVC(),LoginVC()], animated: false)
```

However this causes an infinite loop. Since It runs every time this viewController is loaded, and when it's run, it seems to reload all the viewcontrollers...

I tried putting it in viewDidAppearAnimated instead. But same results. I've since then been trying to put this outside the viewDidLoad or Appear methods. but I can't get it to work since the class doesn't have "navigationController".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I'm not using storyboards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your transitioning **to** ViewController (Dashboard_VC):

```
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
```

In your transitioning **from** Login View Controller:

```
if (successfulLogin) {    
    let mainController = DashBoardViewController()
    mainController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    navigationController!.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: I added both to my project and it does what I wanted. However, I'm having a rough time seeing what the first section of code does? I took it out of my Dashboard_VC and I don't see a change.

as for hiding the button, that only solves my problem on the dashboard and landing page.

What about when I click "sign up" on my login screen. Or visa versa. Those screens still need back buttons, it should just go to the landingPage_VC instead of login or signup. 

Overall thank you so much for the help though, leaps ahead of where I was left of before.

Comment: Since your title says "Programmatically", I assumed you are not using Interface Builder so you will need init(coder aDecoder) to instantiate a new VC in our current version of Swift. The line to hide the Back Button is a method of the View Controller. It only hides for that View Controller. Typically, there is a seperate LogOut process, you don't go back from your main to a LoginVC, but customize as you need. http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/08/initializing-view-controllers-in-swift.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ericgu! I really appreciate the help! You wouldn't happen to also know how to fix my login / signup problem?, Since those pages should still have back buttons, just always take you to the "Landingpage_VC"

Comment: I think you should ask a new question per StackOverFlow's guidelines. Very likely someone will help you.